# 0KB Outlook PST file

Tags: microsoft-outlook

So got a new computer after a long period. Set up everything and it was working just fine. After a reboot, all of my outlook PST files are now 0KB. Literally every one is empty, was previously about 12 GB between 3 PST files and I get an error when I try to open Outlook that my pst file isn't a pst file.

[image]
[image]

Has anyone ever seen this before? I'm afraid of re-adding a PST file because outlook wiped all of them out, even my archive pst file. In 20 years of dealing with MS BS I've never seen anything like this. It's not an issue of file corruption.

Comment: can you recover a pst backup from the first computer. Also see if you can find the pst files with windows explorer

Comment: Likely causes of corruption are Outlook experiencing a dirty closure _(e.g. software failure that resulted in an immediate kill of the application, ending its process in Task Manager/via CLI, etc.)_, filesystem corruption due to malware, or HDD hardware failure _(run a short and long S.M.A.R.T test via [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download))_. You can try `ScanPST`, but it can only recover a corrupted `.pst` file, not repopulate data that's no longer there, or [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)/[`PhotoRec`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, I found some similar threads that mentioned it may occur when your data files are corrupted by other programs, for your reference:

[chkdsk changed my pst file to 0 Kb](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/chkdsk-changed-my-pst-file-to-0-kb/c20f6404-c0d6-4962-8ae8-2ca17aa9c201)

As a suggestion, you could try to follow the suggestions above or repair your data file via Scanpst.exe tool to check.

Comment: I think this might be it. The computer randomly prompted to run chkdsk while I was transferring files from my old one. There was unfortunately no restore point on that file, but I'm betting this is what happened.

Comment: @Jestep Unless you're on Windows 7, `ChkDsk` is likely not the cause; I would view the `ChkDsk` results to verify, but it doesn't seem likely _(google how to access the log after the fact)_. AFAIK, no other program uses the `.pst` extension, with more likely causes being Outlook caused the corruption from a dirty closure, filesystem corruption due to malware, or HDD hardware failure _(run a short and long S.M.A.R.T test via [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download))_; while `ChkDsk` repairs filesystem corruption, it would not be the cause of the corruption.